# GUI runner in Eclipse for Python/IronPython

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, ironpython

As much as the console runner is nice, I enjoy the instant red/green view of a graphical runner such as NUnit or MSTest for quickly glancing at broken tests.

Does such a tool exist for Eclipse? I've tried Google but only found some awful standalone versions.

Comment: Some more research has found that the console runner is currently the only option. Bar creating my own that is.

Answer (score 1):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org) has a [feature](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_launch.html#unit-test-launch) to quickly execute the unit tests from withing the IDE. It also allows selecting the unit test cases to run. But it displays the usual textual output, no graphical representation of the test results.

The best solution I've ever seen (and actively used) is [Wing IDE](http://wingware.com)'s Testing pane, which displays a tree of test results with output and traceback as needed. That's pretty usable, but not for Eclipse, unfortunately. I just mentioned this, because it might help you in some way or give you an idea on how to implement this for Eclipse in the future.